# SQL Join on two tables for messages

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, join

Is it possible for me to join the two tables below?

My aim is to create a query in `ASP.NET` to list all the messages in *Messages* and *Messages2* in one set of data.

**Messages1:**

```
Messages1_ID,
Thread_ID,  
DateCreated,
Title,     
Body
```

**Messages2**:

```
Thread_ID,
Messages2_ID,
DateSent,
DateMsg2Downloaded,
Msg2Subject,
Body
```

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT Messages1.body, Messages2.Body
from Messages1, Messages2
where Messages1 = '9'
```

I have 1 row in *Messages1* and 9 rows in *Messages2* (with a thread id of 9)

But I get all the unique rows in *Messages2*, and for each row returned *Messages1* body is repeated over and over again

I think my tables are designed incorrectly but worth an ask first.

Comment: What is the common field between these two tables? How do they relate to eachother. Is it through the Thread_ID? What is your input and expected output? It's difficult to discern since your SQL isn't giving you what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a union. This will combine the result of two query.

```
SELECT Messages1.body
from Messages1
where Messages1.Thread_ID = '9'
union
SELECT Messages2.Body
from Messages2
where Messages2.Thread_ID = '9'
```

Comment: Should toss a WHERE statement in each of those for `Thead_id = 9`

Comment: @JNevill added it, wasn't sure how to do that part since it's not clear in the question

Comment: This is the one! Thank you all for your really quick responses.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Messages1.body, Messages2.Body
from Messages1 
inner join  Messages2 ON Messages1.Thread_ID  = Messages2.Thread_ID
where Messages1.Thread_ID = '9'
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the code you posted, you want to use an [inner join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx).

To use a join you need a common field between the two tables. I'm going to assume in your case it's threadID.

```
SELECT a.body, b.Body
from Messages1 a
inner join Messages2 b
  on a.Thread_ID = b.Thread_ID
where a.Thread_ID = '9'
```

Answer (score 1):

This Query was also correct but you missed the  condition:`Messages1.ThreadId= Messages2.ThreadId`

```
SELECT Messages1.body, Messages2.Body
from Messages1, Messages2
where Messages1.ThreadId= Messages2.ThreadId and Messages1 = '9'
```

Answer (score 0):

Two different scenarios here as i'm not 100% sure what your exactly after.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT m1.body
FROM Messages1 m1
UNION ALL
SELECT m2.Body
FROM Messages2 m2
)
WHERE ThreadId = '9'
```

OR

```
SELECT m1.body, m2.Body
FROM Messages1 m1
INNER JOIN Messages2 m2 ON m1.ThreadId = m2.ThreadId
WHERE m1.ThreadId = '9'
```

Comment: Edited to remove last 2